# Getting files from /dev using bash completion

Tags: bash, macos, autocomplete, completion

I have a simple question: In my home directory i can type `cat a<tab>tab>` and i get a list of all files starting with an a.
Why, when i use `screen /dev/cu.<tab><tab>` i don't get a list of all files starting with cu. in the /dev directory?

GNU bash, version 5.0.2(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0) 
Homebrew bash-completion@2 innstalled

Contents of .inputrc (nothing completion related)

`"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward`

What am i missing? Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: `/dev` is (IIRC) a special file system. The files may not actually exist until a command like `ls` or a glob expansion tries to query the file system. That is, there is nothing to complete.

Comment: Either that, or the "screen" command is completed by a custom completer. Try checking with "complete -p screen" to see if the completion is default/bashdefault or something else.